# Getting "Unchecked runtime.lastError while running management.uninstall:"

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing a Chrome extension, and in it I want to uninstall another extension. I'm following the docs, but am getting this error:

```
Unchecked runtime.lastError while running management.uninstall: chrome.management.uninstall requires a user gesture.
```

I'm not sure what the cause could be, since I'm making the call like this:

```
chrome.management.uninstall("fgbjpbdfegnodokpoejnbhnblcojccal");
```

I've even tried adding the option with the showDialog boolean to true, but same error. Any help would be appreciated.

The dialog doesn't show, and I simply just get an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can no longer *silently* uninstall *other* extensions since Chrome 34.0.1791.0 ([crbug 178319](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=178319)).
To remove some other extension, the following conditions MUST be satisfied:

1. [`chrome.management.uninstall`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/management#method-uninstall) is called as a response to a user gesture, e.g. a click (on a button)
2. The user must approve the uninstallation request that shows up in the dialog following the uninstall call.

Comment: I see... I originally thought that the only gesture required was approving the uninstallation request via the dialog. There are a lot of potential follow-ups with this new information, but I'll try to resolve them myself before coming back here. Thank you.